# Laplace approximation of Poisson posterior from MacKay

Tags: calculus, probability, factorial, gamma-function, laplace-method

I am doing exercise 27.1 on Laplace's method from [David MacKay's textbook](http://www.inference.org.uk/mackay/itprnn/ps/341.342.pdf), which is to make a Laplace approximation of a Poisson model with an improper prior:

$$
p(x \mid \lambda) = \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^x}{x!}, \quad p(\lambda) = \frac{1}{\lambda}
$$

The posterior is

$$
p(\lambda \mid x) = \frac{p(x \mid \lambda) p(\lambda)}{Z} = \frac{\frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^{x-1}}{x!}}{Z}
$$

where $Z$ is the unknown normalizer. My understanding is that we want a Laplace approximation of

$$
f(x) = \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^{x-1}}{x!}
$$

And this requires taking the second derivative of the log of this function:

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \log f(x)
&= \frac{d}{dx} \Big( -\lambda + (x - 1) \log \lambda - \log x!\Big)
\\\\
&= \frac{d}{dx} \Big( -\lambda + x \log \lambda - \log \lambda - \log x!\Big)
\\\\
&= \log \lambda - \color{red}{\frac{d}{dx} \log x!}
\end{align}

I am stuck on the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ term above. Here is what I have tried:

\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
\frac{d}{dx} \log x!
&= \frac{d}{dx} \log \Gamma(x+1)
\\\\
&= \frac{\Gamma^{\prime}(x+1)}{\Gamma(x+1)}
\\\\
&= \frac{\cancel{\Gamma(x+1)} \psi_0(x+1)}{\cancel{\Gamma(x+1)}}
\\\\
&= \psi_0(x+1)
\end{align}

where $\psi_0$ is the polygamma function. But now I don't know how to compute this derivative.

Comment: maybe use Stirling approximation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer [here](https://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/mlpr/2018/tut/tut7_answers.pdf) is that we can ignore $\log (x!)$ because it does not change the estimate of $\lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) page, the derivative of $\psi_0(x+1)$ is $\psi^{(1)}(x+1)$.

Its series representation can be written as $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{(x+k)^2}=\zeta(2,x+1).$$

Answer (score 0):

The posterior is a function of $\lambda$ so you need to take 1st and 2nd derivatives of the log-posterior wrt to $\lambda$. At that point the factorial $x!$ disappears and so do all terms not depending on $\lambda$ as @gwg mentioned.